# RuntimeError: Expected 4-dimensional input for 4-dimensional weight [64, 512, 3, 3], but got 2-dimensional input of size [32, 2048] instead

Tags: python, deep-learning, neural-network, pytorch, resnet

I want to train a classifier based on a pretrained network with PyTorch. What I need to do is to take a pretrained model (I tried with ResNet50), add some layers at the end (I need to do this as it is required by the project specifications) and train only those layers I add. I tried this:

```
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
from torch.utils.data import DataLoader
import torchvision.transforms as transforms
from torchvision import models
from guitar_dataset import GuitarDataset
from tqdm import tqdm


device = ("cuda" if torch.cuda.is_available() else "cpu")

transformations = transforms.Compose([
    transforms.Resize((200, 200))
])

num_epochs = 10
learning_rate = 0.001
train_CNN = False
batch_size = 32
shuffle = True
pin_memory = True
num_workers = 1

dataset = GuitarDataset(f"../chords_data/cropped/train", transform=transformations)
train_set, validation_set = torch.utils.data.random_split(dataset, [int(0.8 * len(dataset)),
                                                                    len(dataset) - int(0.8 * len(dataset))])
train_loader = DataLoader(dataset=train_set, shuffle=shuffle, batch_size=batch_size, num_workers=num_workers,
                          pin_memory=pin_memory)
validation_loader = DataLoader(dataset=validation_set, shuffle=shuffle, batch_size=batch_size, num_workers=num_workers,
                               pin_memory=pin_memory)

testset = GuitarDataset(f"../chords_data/cropped/test", transform=transformations)
test_loader = DataLoader(dataset=testset, shuffle=shuffle, batch_size=batch_size, num_workers=num_workers,
                         pin_memory=pin_memory)

model = models.resnet50(pretrained=True)
for param in model.parameters():
    param.requires_grad = False
model.fc = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Conv2d(512, 64, (3, 3)),
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.MaxPool2d(2),
            nn.Conv2d(64, 64, (3, 3)),
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.MaxPool2d(2),
            nn.Dropout(0.5),
            nn.Flatten(),
            nn.Linear(147456, 512),
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.Dropout(0.5),
            nn.Linear(512, 64),
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.Dropout(0.5),
            nn.Linear(64, 7)
        )
model.to(device)
criterion = nn.BCELoss()
optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(model.fc.parameters(), lr=learning_rate)


PATH = f"./saved_models/mynet.pth"



def check_accuracy(loader, model):
    if loader == train_loader:
        print("Checking accuracy on training data")
    else:
        print("Checking accuracy on validation data")

    num_correct = 0
    num_samples = 0
    model.eval()

    with torch.no_grad():
        for x, y in loader:
            x = x.to(device=device)
            y = y.to(device=device)

            scores = model(x)
            # predictions = torch.tensor([1.0 if i >= 0.5 else 0.0 for i in scores]).to(device)
            predictions = scores.argmax(1)
            num_correct += (predictions == y).sum()
            num_samples += predictions.size(0)
            print(
                f"Got {num_correct} / {num_samples} with accuracy {float(num_correct) / float(num_samples) * 100:.2f}"
            )
    return f"{float(num_correct) / float(num_samples) * 100:.2f}"


def train():
    model.train()
    for epoch in range(num_epochs + 1):
        loop = tqdm(train_loader, total=len(train_loader), leave=True)
        # if epoch % 2 == 0:
        loop.set_postfix(val_acc=check_accuracy(validation_loader, model))
        if epoch == num_epochs:
            break
        for imgs, labels in loop:
            labels = torch.nn.functional.one_hot(labels, num_classes=7).float()
            imgs = imgs.to(device)
            labels = labels.to(device)
            outputs = model(imgs)
            loss = criterion(outputs, labels)
            optimizer.zero_grad()
            loss.backward()
            optimizer.step()
            loop.set_description(f"Epoch [{epoch + 1}/{num_epochs}]")
            loop.set_postfix(loss=loss.item())

    torch.save(model.state_dict(), PATH)


def test():
    model.load_state_dict(torch.load(PATH))

    correct = 0
    total = 0
    # since we're not training, we don't need to calculate the gradients for our outputs
    with torch.no_grad():
        for data in test_loader:
            images, labels = data
            # calculate outputs by running images through the network
            outputs = model(images)
            # the class with the highest energy is what we choose as prediction
            _, predicted = torch.max(outputs.data, 1)
            total += labels.size(0)
            correct += (predicted == labels).sum().item()

    print('Accuracy of the network on the test images: %d %%' % (
            100 * correct / total))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    print(f"Working on {data_type}")
    train()
    test()
```

but I get the error in the title as soon as I start the training phase. Shouldn't the downloaded model be ready-to-use?

Full stack trace:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/deffo/Documents/Unimore/Magistrale/Computer Vision and Cognitive Systems/Guitar_Fingering_&_Chords_Recognition/ChordsClassification/train_ResNetChord.py", line 139, in <module>
    train()
  File "/home/deffo/Documents/Unimore/Magistrale/Computer Vision and Cognitive Systems/Guitar_Fingering_&_Chords_Recognition/ChordsClassification/train_ResNetChord.py", line 99, in train
    loop.set_postfix(val_acc=check_accuracy(validation_loader, model))
  File "/home/deffo/Documents/Unimore/Magistrale/Computer Vision and Cognitive Systems/Guitar_Fingering_&_Chords_Recognition/ChordsClassification/train_ResNetChord.py", line 83, in check_accuracy
    scores = model(x)
  File "/home/deffo/anaconda3/envs/ComputerVision/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 889, in _call_impl
    result = self.forward(*input, **kwargs)
  File "/home/deffo/anaconda3/envs/ComputerVision/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torchvision/models/resnet.py", line 249, in forward
    return self._forward_impl(x)
  File "/home/deffo/anaconda3/envs/ComputerVision/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torchvision/models/resnet.py", line 244, in _forward_impl
    x = self.fc(x)
  File "/home/deffo/anaconda3/envs/ComputerVision/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 889, in _call_impl
    result = self.forward(*input, **kwargs)
  File "/home/deffo/anaconda3/envs/ComputerVision/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/container.py", line 119, in forward
    input = module(input)
  File "/home/deffo/anaconda3/envs/ComputerVision/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 889, in _call_impl
    result = self.forward(*input, **kwargs)
  File "/home/deffo/anaconda3/envs/ComputerVision/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/conv.py", line 399, in forward
    return self._conv_forward(input, self.weight, self.bias)
  File "/home/deffo/anaconda3/envs/ComputerVision/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/conv.py", line 395, in _conv_forward
    return F.conv2d(input, weight, bias, self.stride,
RuntimeError: Expected 4-dimensional input for 4-dimensional weight [64, 512, 3, 3], but got 2-dimensional input of size [32, 2048] instead
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your network design in wrong.

You are not supposed to add Convolutional layers at the end of `Resnet50`'s feature extractor. Put some `Linear` layers

```
model.fc = nn.Sequential(
            # It has to start from 2048
            nn.Linear(2048, 1024), nn.ReLU(),
            nn.Dropout(0.5),
            nn.Linear(1024, 256), nn.ReLU(),
            nn.Dropout(0.5),
            nn.Linear(1024, 7) # 7 is number of classes
        )
```

The `model.fc` has to start from 2048 units because that's what the `ResNet50`'s feature extractor produces.

The error is basically saying that it was expecting 4D input (because of your Conv2D layer at begining of `model.fc`) but got `(batch_size, 2048)` because that's what the the ResNet50 produced.

Answer (score 1):

You can't replace resnet50's `fc` with a convolutional network. The output of resnet's feature extractor is a CNN which outputs a flat *2048*-long tensor, as such the layers following it should be fully connected layers.

Comment: So what do you suggest to "concatenate" the two networks?

Comment: @Deffo You simply can't, it doesn't make sense to have a CNN following a CNN output. The tensor you get at the resnet50's output level contain features extracted from the image, you simply can't have 2D convolutions following that since the spatial dimensions are.. gone. You should have a classifier following the resnet50 CNN, *i.e.* fully connected layers, **not** convolutions.

Comment: sorry, maybe concatenate is not the right word...I meant merge the two networks. Maybe is possible to sobstitute one of the layers of ResNet with my network? Or to add my network as an additional layer before fully connected (of course, adapting the fc to 7 classes)? What do you think is the best solution?

Comment: @Deffo yes, I understood what you meant by "concatenation". What is your objective exactly? If you don't have a clear idea of what you want to do: if its modifying the resnet architecture, changing the classifier, and/or just fine-tuning `fc`... I think you should start simple by taking the original network and adapting the output level by changing `fc` with a single fully connected layer. That should already give you some results. From there you can improve and add some changes to the architecture.